# How to integrate $\frac{2+5x^3}{2x^3+2}\sqrt{x^3+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How would one find the integral of  $\frac{2+5x^3}{2x^3+2}\sqrt{x^3+1}$ with respect to $x$?

I already know the antiderivative (from Wolfram Alpha), but I don't know how to integrate this function with pencil and paper.
Is there maybe a clever variable substitution?

Comment: Hints: $(2+5x^3)=5(x^3+1)-3$ and $(2x^3+2)=2(x^3+1)$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

I would say that

$\frac{2+5x^3}{2x^3+2}\sqrt{x^3+1}=\frac{2+5x^3}{2(x^3+1)}\frac{x^3+1}{\sqrt{x^3+1}}=\frac{2+5x^3}{2\sqrt{x^3+1}}=\frac{2(x^3+1)+3x^3}{2\sqrt{x^3+1}}=\frac{x^3+1}{\sqrt{x^3+1}}+\frac{3x^3}{2\sqrt{x^3+1}}=$

$=\sqrt{x^3+1}+\frac{3x^3}{2\sqrt{x^3+1}}=1\cdot\sqrt{x^3+1}+x\cdot\frac{3x^2}{2\sqrt{x^3+1}}=\frac{d}{dx}(x\cdot \sqrt{x^3+1})$

Comment: So nice! But you forgot to add the integration constant, the last term should be $${d\over dx}\left(x\sqrt{x^3+1}+C\right)$$

Comment: @DmitryKazakov:  Could be.

Comment: Thanks. But one question: Did you know the antiderivative in advance and then back-solved the problem?

Comment: @AndreiKh: Yes, the problem is back-solved. I find not the antiderivative.